# Understanding to_param from_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 simple scaffolded application having one model like that:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    self.firstname
  end

  def self.from_param param
    self.where(firstname: param).first
  end
end
```

As far as I have read about from_param, everything should work as if to_param was never defined. But it does not work. Rails is still issuing this SQL:

```
SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = 0 LIMIT 1
```

when I try to show/edit the first entry.

I wonder if from_param has any effect at all? [This](http://tomafro.net/tags/from-param) post as well as many others seem to state that. I am unable to get this working.

What am I doing wrong?
Thx for any answer. 
Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails doesn't know anything about from_param - that blog post is manually calling it ( `Model.from_param(params[:id]) )`.  If you're just calling `Contact.find('fred')`, that won't work, it's going to convert 'fred' to an integer (0), and search for that id.